# Can I populate a variable in Knockout and then set it to a hidden variable of my model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Using MVC 4, I am populating a variable with knockout (in a razor view), and I want to pass that variable back to my controller through my viewmodel. For example

```
var selectedProgramOptions;
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: ceraSvcUrl + "/api/Registrations/GetRegistrationOptions?regId=@Model.Registration.Id",
  success: function (result) {
    selectedProgramOptions = result;

       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "jsonp",
       url: ceraSvcUrl + "/api/Programs/GetProgramOptions?programId=@Model.Registration.Program.Id",
       success: function (allProgsResult) {

          if (allProgsResult.length == 0)
             $('#programOptionsDiv').hide();

          for (var i = 0; i < allProgsResult.length; i++) {
             var match = false;
             for (var j = 0; j < selectedProgramOptions.length; j++) {
                if (allProgsResult[i].Name == selectedProgramOptions[j].Name) {
                   match = true;
                   self.AvailableOptions.push(new ProgramOption(selectedProgramOptions[j].Name, selectedProgramOptions[j].ChargeCode, selectedProgramOptions[j].Price, true, selectedProgramOptions[j].Notes, selectedProgramOptions[j].OptionGroup));
                 }
             }
             var chgCode = allProgsResult[i].ChargeCode;
             if (match == false && ["TG", "TN", "TP", "TV", "TW", "E2", "E3", "L2", "L3"].indexOf(chgCode) <= -1)
                self.AvailableOptions.push(new ProgramOption(allProgsResult[i].Name, allProgsResult[i].ChargeCode, allProgsResult[i].Price, false, allProgsResult[i].Notes, allProgsResult[i].OptionGroup));
             }
          }
      });

 }
 });
```

This is the code to populate the knockout field is the self.AvailableOptions. I need to put that field into @Model.Registration.AvailableOptions.

Comment: `self.AvailableOptions` is populated on client, there is no `@Model.Registration.AvailableOptions` anymore. Since all data is on server anyway, why do you want to set `@Model.Registration.AvailableOptions`?

Comment: Could you share your `View`, `Model` and `Controller` code?